# Why $f_x(x)=\frac1{3x^{2/3}}$ is not continuous at $x=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

Im reading a book of differential equations and at some point it says that the function defined by $f_x(x)=\frac1{3x^{2/3}}$ is not continuous at $x=0$, but $x=0$ is not a point of the domain of $f_x$ because the function is not defined at it.

Then it is correct to say that if a function is not defined at some point then it is not continuous at this point either?

---

Background: the function comes from the initial value problem defined by

$$x'=x^{1/3}=:f(x),\quad x(0)=0\tag1$$ From here the book used the partial derivative of $f$ respect to $x$, that is

$$f_x(x):=\partial_x f(x)=\frac1{3x^{2/3}}$$

and the fact that $f_x$ is not continuous at $x=0$ is used to show that, from some theorem about uniqueness of solutions, that the solutions to $(1)$ could be not unique, in this case it is shown that there are infinite solutions.

Comment: What exactly is the differential equation given? Because if it is $x'(t)=x(t)^{1/3}$ (which is what it looks like you're trying to write at the beginning), then you don't get to the solution by differentiating the right-hand side with respect to $x$.

Comment: I updated with a better explanation @Arthur. The book dont used the partial derivative to find solutions, just to show that some theorem about uniqueness doesnt hold in this case.

Comment: Since (my perception of) the question changed with the edit, I don't have an immediate answer. However, here are two thoughts: 1) Several techniques in differential equations are on shaky theoretical ground (just look at what physicists do when they're confronted with one), but that's OK, since what matters is that we get an answer to our equation which can be checked. 2) Are discontinuous solutions allowed? $x(t)=t^{3/2}+ c$ for $t> 0$, $x(t)=t^{3/2}+d$ for $t<0$ and $x(0)=0$ would have exactly the same derivative as $t^{3/2}$.

Comment: sorry for the previous lack of context @Arthur, anyway I think that your answer fit to the question. The book is *The theory of differential equations* of Kelley and Peterson. In this context discontinuous functions are not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global question is if the existence and uniqueness theorem can be applied. For that you would need local Lipschitz continuity of $f$. This would be the case if $f$ were differentiable and $f_x$ bounded over some interval (containing $x=0$). This in turn would be automatic if $f_x$ were continuous.

But the point is that $f_x$ is not even defined at $x=0$ and further unbounded in every neighborhood of $x=0$ preventing the existence of any Lipschitz constant. As a different example, consider $f(x)=|x|$ which is also not differentiable in $x=0$ but has bounded derivative around $x=0$ and is indeed Lipschitz continuous (trivially by the triangle inequality).

You can demonstrate non-uniqueness by observing that $x(t)=0$ and $x(t)=(\frac23t)^{3/2}$ are both solutions, and thus have an infinity of further solutions with $x(0)=0$ between them.

Comment: I see... The book introduced a theorem of existence and uniqueness (without proof, but the proof would be shown in the last chapter of the book) in a simple way, where there is no mention to Lipschitz continuity, just to continuity of the partial derivative of $f(t,x)$ respect to $x$. Maybe I would like to read a more formal book about the topic.

Comment: Yes, that is the version attributed to Cauchy, the more general theorem is Picard-Lindelöf. But the simple non-differentiability does not imply non-uniqueness, it just identifies areas where something "interesting" might happen.